# Opening .JSON file fails on Ubuntu

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a python application that uses the bokeh library to display a google maps plot with [GMapPlot](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/map_plots.html). In order to change the map style with [GMapOptions](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/map_plots.html) I'm reading [this](https://snazzymaps.com/style/132/light-gray) .JSON file which is stored locally at ./map/styles.JSON and converting it to a string. On Win10 this works fine with

```
with open(r"./map/styles.JSON", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    styles = file.read().splitlines()
styles="".join(styles)
```

However, when I'm running the application on an Ubuntu server an error is raised

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "photo_map.py", line 22, in <module>
with open(r"./map/styles.JSON", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Without the encoding statement a new error is raised

```
ValueError: expected JSON text, got '\xef\xbb\xbf[...
..."#dadada"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n]'
```

I also tried to work with the json module and decode() method without any success.

Declaring a variable within my python script that contains the .JSON data as string works fine on Win10 and Ubuntu but is obviously only a workaround.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the Ubuntu server is running Python 3.x ?

Comment: You're running it with Python 2.x. Try: `with codecs.open("./map/styles.JSON", "utf-8") as file: ...` (of course, don't forget to `import codecs`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open("./map/styles.JSON", "rb") as file:
    styles = file.read().decode("utf-8-sig").splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and used https://jsonlint.com/ to verify the json file.
The problem: Windows gave the file EOL (end of line) characters that linux doesn't use. 
The solution: I opened the file in Notepad++ from the menu - Edit >> EOL Conversion >> Unix (LF)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has the `encoding` keyword for `open()` but Python 2 doesn't.

You probably need to make sure you execute the script in Python 3 if that's what it was designed for.  On many servers, `python` always refers to Python 2, and the Python 3 binary is called `python3`.